# How do I get fake slant (italics) with XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, slanted

I am setting my font using this:

```
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Tahoma}
```

But text labelled `\textit` or `\itshape` isn't appearing italicised. is there a way to setup fake italics?

Answer (score 12):

`\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{Tahoma}`

The number determines the severity of the slant. I don't have Tahoma installed so I don't know what looks good with it.

Search the [fontspec](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) manual for "FakeSlant" to see more options.