# Slanted text to the left

Tags: fonts, slanted

How can I get slanted text to the left instead?
Instead of the usual way slant/italic slants to the right.

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Not, yet. Looked around on the internet but couldn't seem to find anything. It's for a personal project so I didn't want to lose hours of time if anyone just knew the answer.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: What font?  Slant is normally a property of the font.  If it's a Metafont, you could do this; but we need more information to help.

Comment: Related: [How do I get fake slant (italics) with XeLaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3159/5764)

Comment: Also, do you want entire paragraphs, or just some short text snippet to be slanted left?

Comment: Werner's comment is probably your easiest answer; just set the slant to a negative value.

Comment: There are fonts which feature a left-slanted shape. Those would probably give the best results if you can track down a suitable family. (Especially if this is for a significant amount of text rather than just the odd word.)

Answer (score 7):

Taking Bruno's answer at [Shear transform a "box"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63179/shear-transform-a-box/63188#63188), `\slantbox[slant]{text}` will give leftward slant for negative values of `slant`.  The larger the absolute value of `slant`, the more the slant.  I'm speculating that the value of `slant` is the tangent of the slant angle, relative to the vertical aspect.

The default is no slant, but once `slant` is set with the optional argument, it will persist for future invocations at that value until changed again in the optional argument.

This EDITED solution **will** line wrap.  The code has be RE-EDITED to restore kerning and ligatures, by processing words, rather than characters at a time.  However, hyphenation is not possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox\foobox
\def\slantvalue{0}
\newcommand{\slantboxengine}[2][\slantvalue]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\slantbox[2][\slantvalue]{%
  \edef\slantvalue{#1}\expandafter\slantboxhelpA#2 \relax\relax}
\def\slantboxhelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \slantboxengine{#1}%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\ \slantboxhelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\begin{document}
\slantbox[-.3]{%
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

NEW METHOD RESTORES LIGATURES

\slantbox{fififififi flflflflfl}

PRIOR METHOD:

\def\slantboxhelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \slantboxhelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \slantboxhelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\slantboxhelpB#1#2\relax{%
  \slantboxengine{#1}%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \slantboxhelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}
\slantbox{fififififi flflflflfl}

\end{document}
```

[image]